# How to Get Data from other Scene in Phaser3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I've seen answers to other questions similar to mine, with passing the data through scene.start() adn getting it with the init function. But I am asking something different.

Let's say I am on Scene A, which is starts Scene B and is paused. Then I do some calculations on Scene B and I want to pass that result to scene A, when I resume it.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-phaser-resume-data

Similar to passing data with start. There’s also an optional data parameter for calls like resume. Which is passed to the listener of scene resume events.

```
// scene-a #create
this.events.on('resume', (scene, data) => {
    this.textObj.setText(data.someMath.toString());
});

// scene-b
this.game.scene.resume('scene-a', {someMath});
```

Alternatively, you can scope something from another scene and register a resume event listener from there instead.

```
// scene-b
const sceneA = this.game.scene.getScene('scene-a');
sceneA.events.once('resume', () => {
    sceneA.textObj.setText('something from this scene, scene-b');
});
this.game.scene.resume('scene-a');
```